# Display lins from text.file to array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, split, text-files

I am trying to read lines from txt file into array and display it into a text box.
Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack != true)
    {
        blogPostTextBox.Text ="";
        string blogFilePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blogs.txt";
        string[] blogMessageArray = File.ReadAllLines(blogFilePath);

        // this for loop code does not work..I think.. 
        for (int i = 0; i < blogMessageArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] fileLineArray = blogMessageArray[i].Split(' ');
            blogPostTextBox.Text = blogMessageArray[i] + System.Environment.New Line.ToString();
        }   
    }
}
```

My text file contains several line and I am trying to split each line to array and display all lines into a text box using a for loop or while loop.

Comment: So what is the problem ???

Comment: What is the error/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append each line to the textbox. What you are doing above is overwriting the contents of the textbox with each new line.

```
string[] blogMessageArray = File.ReadAllLines("");
blogPostTextBox.Text = "";
foreach (string message in blogMessageArray)
{
    blogPostTextBox.Text += message + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Although rather than read in all the lines, and then write out all the lines, why don't you just write out all the text to the textbox?

```
blogPostTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText();
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

For **ASP.Net**

```
var items =File.ReadAllLines(blogFilePath).SelectMany(line => line.Split()).Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
blogPostTextBox.Text=string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items)
```

and as a side note, it is better to use `Path.Combine` when you build path from multiple strings

```
string blogFilePath = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~") , "Blogs.txt");
```

also `if (IsPostBack != true)` is valid but you can do as

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

---

**Winform**

If the Multiline property of the text box control is set to true, you can use [**`TextBoxBase.Lines Property`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx)

```
blogPostTextBox.Lines =File.ReadAllLines(blogFilePath);
```

if you need to split each line and set as textbox text then

```
blogPostTextBox.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(blogFilePath).SelectMany(line => line.Split()).ToArray();
```

Comment: nice didn't know there was a Lines property

Comment: I assume this is ASP.NET since OP used `IsPostBack` property and `Server.MapPath`, there is no `Lines` property on an [ASP.NET-`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_properties.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [`TextMode="MultiLine"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx) in your `TextBox`(default value is `SingleLine`), then you could build the text with Linq in this way:

```
var allLinesText = blogMessageArray
     .SelectMany(line => line.Split().Select(word => word.Trim()))
     .Where(word => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(word));
blogPostTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allLinesText);
```

Comment: 1+ why there is two times join with `Environment.NewLine` and it will produce empty lines

Answer (score 0):

Though you could do this in a loop, you really don't need to (or want to)

Replace your loop with with built in dot net methods that actually do what your need.

```
See String.Join()

public static string Join(
    string separator,
    params string[] value
)
```

This will combine all of the elements of blogMessageArray with your specified separator 
('\n' in your case, HTML does not need "\r\n")

Then just assign this to the property blogPostTextBox.Tex